# etcdctl snapshot status cannot get hush of bucket

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, etcdctl

I am learning k8s and had an exercise to backup etcd data, so I used the command:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot save --endpoints localhost:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key mysnap.db
```

which worked nicely :) but then when I tried to get the snapshot status with:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot status mysnap.db
```

and with:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot status --endpoints localhost:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key mysnap.db
```

in both situations I got the error message:

> Error:  cannot get hash of bucket �_

I tried to understand why but did not find out a lot, only the section of the source code where the error message jump from (in golang) in this URL:
https://fossies.org/linux/etcd/clientv3/snapshot/v3_snapshot.go

etcdctl version: 3.2.26

Comment: Where are you performing those exercises? Where is your cluster running?

Comment: @Crou hi, I perform those exercises on my own ubuntu 19.10, with Kubernetes 1.18 installed. the Kubernetes deployed with the Kubeadm tool.